# replace values in an array

Tags: python, numpy

as a replacement value for another within an operation with arrays, or how to search within an array and replace a value by another

for example:

```
array ([[NaN, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]
       [1., NaN, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]
       [1., 1., NaN, 1., 1., 1., 1.]
       [1., 1., 1., NaN, 1., 1., 1.]
       [1., 1., 1., 1., NaN, 1., 1.]
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., NaN, 1.]
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., NaN]])
```

where it can replace NaN by 0.
thanks for any response

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could do this:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([[np.NaN, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],[1., np.NaN, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],[1., 1., np.NaN, 1., 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., np.NaN, 1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., np.NaN, 1., 1.],[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., np.NaN, 1.], [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., np.NaN]])
x[np.isnan(x)]=0
```

`np.isnan(x)` returns a boolean array which is `True` wherever `x` is `NaN`.
`x[ boolean_array ] = 0` employs [fancy indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-d55e594d46b4f347c20efe1b4c65c92779f06268) to assign the value 0 wherever the boolean array is `True`.

For a great introduction to fancy indexing and much more, see also [the numpybook](http://www.tramy.us/).

Comment: @ricardo: Let x be your numpy array.

Answer (score 15):

these days there is the special function:

```
a = numpy.nan_to_num(a)
```

Comment: Just saved my bacon while doing in Inverse Filter. [image-processing]

Comment: But this will involve a temporary variable with same type and shape as ```a```, it will matter on large matrices.

Comment: @dashesy As of version 1.13 you can do in place: a = numpy.nan_to_num(a, copy=False)  ... More information on the parameter 'copy': Whether to create a copy of x (True) or to replace values in-place (False). The in-place operation only occurs if casting to an array does not require a copy. Default is True.
New in version 1.13.

Comment: Any way to choose a fill value other than 0?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example array in the question:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.where(np.eye(7), np.nan, 1)
```

You can either use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [numpy.isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) functions to create a new array `b`:

```
b = np.where(np.isnan(a), 0, a)
```

Or use an in-place function to directly modify the `a` array:

```
np.place(a, np.isnan(a), 0)  # returns None
```